# Is ionic will slow down the process with multiple pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've started with ionic and angular.
In our app we are just showing the data we're getting from server. But there will be 20+ pages. And I've checked Ionic docs, It's mentioned that Ionic will maintain the history and state. So is that will slow down the performance of app if multiple pages are loaded in background ?

I faced a lot of issues in one of my app(which was completely JS and JQuery based), because we were running 3 threads in background, it was slowing down the UI, UI was too much jerky in that case.

Just want to take care about this, your suggestion is worth a lot for me.
Thanks

Comment: ionic 1 or ionic 2?

Comment: Not sure i follow you, do you plan to pre-render all pages at first load? A page doesnt say anything, what will a page consist of?

Comment: from what you are saying ionic doesn't save pages but history and state, so you should only have problems with the state